# UIButton sets dark when it is selected (I want to avoid this)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing an iOS 4 application.

I'm using a custom uibutton to make an image clickable. When user taps over the image, it will disappear.

It's not very pretty to see that the image gets black, then turns to its original color, and then disappear.

Is there a way to disable that effect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will need to set the property `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to NO:

```
[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
```

Alternatively you can set the same image for all controlStates of the button.

Comment: In Swift: `button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the property Shows Touch On Highlight to enabled.

Programmatically you can do that with:

```
[button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

Comment: This would only add a glow effect when highlighting the button, but will still adjust the image to be slightly darker.

Comment: @FelixLam is incorrect. Setting `setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted` to YES disables Apple's "darken image if no image (nil) is set for highlighted state" rule and overwrites it with the new highlighting rule.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a custom button, you get to specify the image you want to show when it's highlighted. Create the image you want to show in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface builder just set the Highlighted and selected states to the same image as the default image.